# random generated strings, possible to be equals?

Tags: php

given a script that generates a string of 12 characters randomly generated, how many possibilities there are for two string to be equal?

```
function rand_string( $length ) {
    $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";  

    $size = strlen( $chars );
    for( $i = 0; $i < $length; $i++ ) {
        $str .= $chars[ rand( 0, $size - 1 ) ];
    }

    return $str;
}
```

Comment: An infinite number. Try again.

Comment: Warning: uninitialised variable `$length` in index.php line 5.

Comment: 62^12, or in other words, many.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming, `A-Za-z0-9`, there are 62 possible character values.  Therefore, there are 62^12 (to-the-power-of) possible strings.  That's roughly 3x10^21 (3 with 21 zeros).

Assuming a perfect random number generator, that's a 1 in 3x10^21 chance that any two particular strings will be equal.

Comment: From one call to the next, sure. More than 2 calls results in a higher chance each time.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: "More than 2 calls results in a higher chance each time." -- false, events are independent.

Comment: He didn't ask about probabilities. He asked about the number of possible pairs.

Comment: @Thilo: Or it is just poorly phrased.

Comment: @zerkms: There's a higher probability of finding a collision *somewhere*.  Obviously, the probability between neighbouring pairs remains constant.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: nope, the probability of independent events is constant regardless of number of iterations.

Comment: @Thilo: and there is infinite number of possible pairs.

Comment: @zerkms: What?  If I generate 4 random strings, there's a higher probability that there'll be a collision somewhere than if I only generate 3 random strings.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: oh, now you're talking about collision among already generated strings :-S sorry, i misunderstood. I thought we're talking about the probability of occurring some particular random string, which is obviously constant. So, yes, probability raises with each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Given that code and a length of 12, there are 62<sup>12</sup> possible values. So (assuming a perfectly uniform random number generator, which `rand()` probably isn't) the chances are 1 in 3226266762397899821056 that a single call to that function will return any arbitrary 12-character string.

OTOH, if you are calling the function repeatedly and want to know how long until you are likely to get a repeat of any previously returned value, you would have to call it about 6.7e+10 times to have a 50% chance of a collision (again, assuming a uniform random number generator). You can get a reasonable approximation of the number of calls required for any collision probability *p* between 0 and 1 by calculating `sqrt(-ln(1 - p) * 2 * 6212)`.

Answer (score 1):

This falls under the Birth Paradox (how many people do you need in a room to have a 50% chance of two or more people having the same birthday).

Your 12-long 62-char strings come out to be about 72 bits. With the approximate detailed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack), you can expect to generate about SQRT((pi / 2) * 62^12)) = 7.112x10^10 strings before getting a collision. So about 1 in 70 billion.